# How to wtite Erlang B and Erlang C formulas in Python

Tags: python, traffic

I need to use Erlang B and Erlang C formulas in python script.

- [Erlang B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28unit%29#Erlang_B_formula)
- [Erlang C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28unit%29#Erlang_C_formula)

How can I write these formulas in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking for a scientific python library like scipy :=)

```
from math import factorial
def ErlangB (E, m):
    InvB = 1.0
    for j in range(1, m+1):
        InvB = 1.0 + InvB * (j/E)
    return (1.0 / InvB)

def ErlangC(A, N):
    L = (A**N / factorial(N)) * (N / (N - A))
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(N):
        sum_ += (A**i) / factorial(i)
    return (L / (sum_ + L))
```

( According to wikipedia pseudo-code)

Comment: This code looks good and the Erlang C function is working properly when I add a condition `if (N-A<=0): return 1 else: _your code here_`

Comment: unfortunately it is slow for large numbers of A and N and sometimes overflow error appears like this `sum_ += (A**i)/factorial(i)
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float`

Comment: maybe You could implement these functions in C and provide a python module in order to acces those functions. But i don't know if there is a real advantage to do this (in term of performance)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be wrong for large-ish numbers, probably due to the tremendously huge floats that result from the powers and factorials. As a sanity check, ErlangC(48, 55) should be 0.239, but this implementation yields 0.247.

Comment: I modified the code to use Python's [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), and that increased the accuracy of the calculations; in ErlangC, casting A and N to decimal.Decimal made `ErlangC(48, 55)` return approximately 0.2387.

Comment: You can check  [Pyworkforce](https://pypi.org/project/pyworkforce/), it already has a build in ErlangC implementation