# How to calculate amount of call center's operators? Erlang Calculator on python

Tags: python

I have stuck with a problem of predicting how many operators are needed for call center to answer the calls (80%) in less than 20 seconds (in queue). Just something like [this Erlang Calculator](https://www.callcentrehelper.com/tools/erlang-calculator/)

But I need to implement that in a python script. I did found [basic Erlang-c formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528145/how-to-wtite-erlang-b-and-erlang-c-formulas-in-python) but it only returns probability that an arriving customer will need to queue.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def ErlangC(A, N):
    if (N-A<=0): 
        return 1 
    L = (A**N / factorial(N)) * (N / (N - A))
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(N):
        sum_ += (A**i) / factorial(i)
    return (L / (sum_ + L))

def calc_sl(row):
    if row['duration'] == 0:
        return 0
    A = row['duration']
    T = 20 # targeted waiting time
    aht = row['duration'] * 3600 / row['calls']
    for staff in range(1000):
        P = ErlangC(A, staff)
        sl = (1 - (P * math.exp(-((staff - A) * (T / aht))))) * 100
        if sl >= 80: # percent of calls to be in tagreted waiting time
            return staff
```

Comment: um, is this your answer?

Comment: yes, I resolved that issue with google and linked thread on stack overflow (first function) and showed code that I ended up using. I wrote it here, because thought it might be useful for someone in future

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyworkforce](https://pypi.org/project/pyworkforce/) for this problem, you just need to define your parameters and goals (all the time parameters are in minutes), for example:

```py
from pyworkforce.queuing import ErlangC

erlang = ErlangC(transactions=100, asa=20/60, aht=3, interval=30, shrinkage=0.3)

positions_requirements = erlang.required_positions(service_level=0.8, max_occupancy=0.85)
print("positions_requirements: ", positions_requirements)
```

This will return the needed resources considering shrinkage = 0 (raw_resources), the resources under the provided shrinkage, the probability that a transaction waits in the queue, the expected service level and the expected resources occupancy

Output:

```py
{'raw_positions': 14,
 'positions': 20,
 'service_level': 0.8883500191794669,
 'occupancy': 0.7142857142857143, 
 'waiting_probability': 0.1741319335950498}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's something new :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed Argos code a little bit and now it works for me. Argos code worked but didn't show the same results as the online Erlang C calculators. I tested it with multiple Erlang C calculators (also the one linked in this post) and multiple examples and the code shows the same results as the online calculators.

```
def ErlangC(A, N):
    if (N-A<=0): 
        return 1 
    L = (A**N / factorial(N)) * (N / (N - A))
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(N):
        sum_ += (A**i) / factorial(i)
    return (L / (sum_ + L))

def calc_sl(row):
    if row['duration'] == 0:
        return 0
    
    T = 60 # targeted waiting time
    A = (row['calls'] * row['duration']) / 3600 # A as in Erlang C formula from Wikipedia
    aht = row['duration'] 

    for staff in range(1000):
        P = ErlangC(A, staff)
        sl = (1 - (P * math.exp(-((staff - A) * (T / aht))))) * 100
        if sl >= 80: # percent of calls to be in targeted waiting time
            return staff
```